# UIImagePickerController pushing views up 20px

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal view controller containing:

```
    imagePickerController_ = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController_.delegate = (id)self;
    imagePickerController_.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController_.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -20.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
    [self.view addSubview:imagePickerController_.view];
```

You'll notice I have had to manually move the view up 20px because for some reason it was sitting too low.

When I dismiss the modal view controller all the views contained within the view of the view controller beneath get pushed up 20px (even though the view itself keeps the same original coordinates).

In other words I have a view controller `A` which controls view `A`. View `A` also contains view `B`, `C` and `D`. I then push modal view controller `X` onto view controller `A` to show an image picker controller with the code above. When modal view controller `X` gets dismissed view controller `A` is shown again with view `A` intact, but views `B`, `C` and `D` are moved 20px up. **How can I prevent this from happening**?

Comment: 20px sounds like status bar issue.

Comment: @Chakalaka I would assume so too. The question is how to fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered what the problem was. Unfortunately it would have been difficult to see the error from my post.

I was placing the `imagePickerController` in another view controller which was being presented modally. I am now ***directly*** presenting modally the `imagePickerController`.

```
imagePickerController_ = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController_.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePickerController_.delegate = (id)self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController_ animated:YES];
```

Sorry for the hassle. I hope this helps others not to make the same mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, when you add that `imagePickerController_` you need to set it's frame to bounds of A viewController. Like `imagePickerController_.view.frame = self.view.bounds`.

---

You can find more about view coordinate systems at [View and Window Architecture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW5).

Also read about [naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html), naming `imagePickerController_` pretty strange. May be you meant `_imagePickerController`. And I think it's better to use [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) for this purpose. So access it with `self.imagePickerController`.

Also check out [Presenting View Controllers from Other View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html).

Comment: Setting `imagePickerController_` to `self.view.bounds` didn't work. On another note, I'm not sure why properties would be better for this purpose.

Comment: By setting `imagePickerController_` you mean `imagePickerController_.view.frame`?
For debugging I can recommend `NSLog(@"frame = %@, bounds = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(<#CGRect rect#>), NSStringFromCGRect(<#CGRect rect#>));`
I don't remember exactly, but look at property `self.wantsFullScreenLayout`